# combine two half images of logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a webpage with an animation in which I have a 3D model logo (it has 2 parts, one is right & 2nd is the left part.) and there is a text between them that will pop up when that 3D model became split on mouse-hover. before splitting that 3D model shows as one image like a full logo. Anyone who can help me? thanks

Comment: Please simplify you answer by removing all but the core of your code :) Also, how do you want halfs? Left/right op top/bottom?

Comment: Also, if you can, you can use the 'javascript snippet' tool to create an example based of what you have now

Comment: I want to combine the left side of logo with right side of logo. My logo is 3D model.

Comment: I have a figma file ad video for expalining what I want....I dont want know how can I share that here at this platform...can you help me in this regard plz?

Comment: Please don't make multiple accounts and write the same question again and again without improvements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433195/combine-2-split-images

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logoHalf {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 200%; /* twice the width to only show half */
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left {
  background-image: url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-red-square-grunge-stamp-600w-327662909.jpg');
  background-position: left center; /* this one from the left */
}

#right {
  background-image: url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/vasilyrosca/vasilyrosca1912/vasilyrosca191200495/137253397-beispiel-f%C3%BCr-ein-vektorstempelsymbol-beispiel-wasserzeichen-stempel-.jpg');
  background-position: right center; /* this one from the right */
}
```

```html
<div id="left" class="logoHalf"></div>
<div id="right" class="logoHalf"></div>
```

Comment: here is the link (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f-TDvhDv2jWm0o8Q-z6FqasnzPiX9Nnj?usp=sharing) of kindly check it. the video is embedded and where things are explained better.

Comment: Im sorry, Im not going to open files from strangers on the internet. Nothing personal, just good pratice :)